# Let ${x_n}=2^{n}a_n$, and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}{2}}, a_0=1$, how to prove ${x_n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, recurrence-relations

How to show $x_n=2^na_n$ converges, where $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}{2}}$

The question originated from Professor David McKinnon.

Attempt:
I did prove it is increasing but failed to show it is bounded above. The sequence should converge to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, if I'm not mistaking.

In addition, ${a_n}$ is a decreasing sequence, and it is bounded below by 0, so I tried to use the fact that ${a_n}$ is a Cauchy to prove that ${x_n}$ is also a Cauchy.

Comment: Hint: $\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}}{2}}$.

Comment: To prove $x_n$ is increasing, all we need to do is to show that $2a_{n+1}>a_n$. Rewrite $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$, and after some algebraic work, we can show the desired conclusion.

Comment: @achillehui In fact, we are using this to construct the sine function(we used $a_n$ to construct $sin(\frac{pi x}{2})$), so I don't think using your hint here is a good idea, as it may result circular reasoning. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\frac{a_{n+1}^2}{a_n^2} =  \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-a_n^2}}{2a_n^2} = \frac{1}{2(1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2})} \le \frac{1}{2}$$

We have

$$a_n^2 = a_0^2 \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k^2}{a_{k-1}^2} \le 2^{-n}
\quad\implies\quad
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k^2 \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} = 2$$

Since

$$\frac{x_{n+1}^2}{x_n^2} = \frac{4a_{n+1}^2}{a_n^2}
= \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}
= 1 + \frac{1-\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}
= 1 + \frac{a_n^2}{(1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2})^2}$$

We find

$$1 \le \frac{x_{n+1}^2}{x_n^2} \le 1 + a_n^2 \le e^{a_n^2}$$

LHS tells us the sequence $(x_n)$ is increasing while RHS tells us it is bounded from above.
$$x_n^2 = x_0^2 \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k^2}{x_{k-1}^2}
\le \prod_{k=1}^n e^{a_{k-1}^2} = e^{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k^2}
< e^{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k^2} = e^2$$

As a result, sequence $(x_n)$ converges to some number $\le e$.